# FAQ refers to Stack Apps

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the reputation section of the FAQ there are three references to Stack Apps. This is also true of the meta FAQ.

[image: nothing of value]

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was copied and pasted from Stack Apps as that was the newest site. I also guess that it will be changed when the site leaves beta.